# Is it valid Serilog code to put a "$" in front of a string?

Tags: c#, serilog

I am not familiar with Serilog.  I am going over the code because as of yet it is not writing its information to Splunk.  I think I have figured out the problem but I would like someone to confirm my hypothesis.

```
splunkLog.Information($"An account for user '{userName}' was successfully created");
```

Is there any reason for an $ to be placed in front of a string like this?  All I can find in the documentation is the $ is used in front of properties for serialization.  I can't find any reference to using it in front of a string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is string interpolation feature of c#

Comment: Specifically, this feature was added in C# 6.

Comment: here is the link about string interpolation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Thank you very much!  At least now I know that this isn't the problem.

Comment: You might do some searching and reading about serilog and how it relates to string interpolation. You may end up with log messages and unintended properties in your logs. Using the $ vs not changes how semantic logging works. For example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200484/why-logging-doesnt-use-string-interpolation

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
splunkLog.Information($"An account for user '{userName}' was successfully created");
```

is considered bad form with Serilog, because it will produce an unstructured log message (text log), with `userName` formatted into the string before Serilog sees it.

The alternative:

```
splunkLog.Information("An account for user '{UserName}' was successfully created", userName);
```

will produce a structured log event. The message will be the same, but Serilog will also capture a separate property `UserName` with the value of `userName` in it. **Much** nicer if you want to search/analyze logs based on the username.